# how to convert from type logical to matrice

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-compiler

```
function MatB = MBin_Init
N=6;
P=4;
SM=1;
while(SM>0)
    MatBin=rand(P,N)>=0.5;
    sv = sum(MatBin,2)==0;
    SM = sum(sv);
end
MatB.MatBin = MatBin ;
end
```

This function create a random binary matrices of size(P,N).
Then i have created an other to search if there is a colomn  of zeros in matrix1 at position p, if yes then matrix2 take a column of zeros too in the same position p.

```
function [ MatB1 ] = Replace( )
MatBin1 = MBin_Init();
MatBin2 = MBin_Init();
indexColonneNulle = 0;
for i=1:4
   if sum(MatBin1(:,i)) == 0
        indexColonneNulle = i;
   end
end
if(indexColonneNulle > 0)
    MatBin2(:,indexColonneNulle) = 0;
end
MatB1.MatBin2 = MatBin2;
end
```

An error appear when executing these functions!!
Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in Replace (line 6)
    if sum(MatBin1(:,i)) == 0

What i have to do please??
thanks

Comment: For some reason you are returning `MatB.MatBin` from `MBin_Init`. Just set `MatB = MatBin;`

Comment: Further, use the debugger, set a breakpoint at line 6 in `Replace` or call `dbstop if error` before running `Replace`. It will jump right to line where it fails, there you can inspect the variables.

Comment: To complement Jørgen's comment: ... or `sum(MatBin1.MatBin(:,i))`. Note that using `i` and `j` as variable names in MATLAB is discouraged, as they're predefined as the imaginary unit. (But overloading them is fine if you're never working with complex numbers)